# Editing a html file within another html with GitHub

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, github

I have a chat bot which queues songs in an array and plays them one after another.

My question is, what would be the best way to display the song list?

I have a **Github** repository acting as a web host for my domain.

HomePage of website *www.website.com*

Would edit the *ul element* in songlist.html

Song list displayed on *www.website.com/songlist.html*

Since Github does not execute server-side code, I would have to find a way to edit an element in another HTML file.

Anyone mind giving a hint, or at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [mcve]. Also see [ask], and check out the [help].

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com), which is included as part of GitHub Pages.

In the root of your repository, add a folder called `_includes`. Put the file that you want to access in there (let's say `include-me.html`). Then in your html page, add six dashes to the top of your HTML file like so:

```
---
---

Your HTML...
```

Then in you can include the file like so:

```
{% include include-me.html %}
```

P.S. your question is not very clear, I hope I interpreted it right.